# Crassula ovata/Jade plant: leaf tips shrunk in

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care, jade

I have several crassula plants, and the leaf tips on some of them started appearing shrunk in, as if something chewed them of or sucked them out (see image). I can't see any bugs on the plants. They're near an east-facing window, and I've been trying to keep them rather dry than wet.

Any ideas what this can be?
[image: Jade plant with leaf tips shrunk in]